# Necessary and sufficient condition for linear transformation having charactristic 2 to be self-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there any necessary and sufficient condition for linear transformation on the vector space having characteristic 2 to be self-inverse?

Comment: If a matrix $A$ is self-inverse, then $A^2 = I$, so its minimal polynomial is either $x - 1$ or $x^2 - 1$.  Does that help?